# How to deal with the scratch in powder coated aluminium roller unit

Tags: paint, aluminum, scratches

I recently installed some roller window units made of Powder coated aluminium.

It's hardly two weeks , after seeing this scratch and I wonder ,Is it even the power coated aluminium as they mentioned.

Any ideas how to ascertain if it's the powder coated aluminium as they mentioned otherwise it's just a milky white painting on top of aluminium.

How to deal with this scratch

[image]

Comment: Powder coat will break off a bit like enamel if knocked. It's less 'glassy' than enamel, and easier to damage. It's tougher than paint but not indestructible. That looks pretty thin, but there's not enough detail in the photo to say much more.

Comment: I mean, if it's me I just get some white paint...maybe enamel?...and a Q-tip.

Comment: That may not be a scratch. It may be something marked black on "it", ( whatever the pic is).  Bottom line is get some white paint and touch it up. It's miniscule.

Comment: @Huesmann - I will apply and see thanks

Comment: @RMDman - I'm wondering if I am sold non powder coated material ? I just want to be sure.It actually scrach .. it's like white got scrape and black background appears

Comment: @Tetsujin - I just want to be sure .. if it's really powder coated or white painted aluminium ?

Comment: Powder coat tends to be thicker, but there's a crossover where it could be either. Powder also tends to be slightly 'bumpier'. If you want to be sure, put paint stripper on a test portion. If it's paint it will start to bubble almost immediately, powder coat will take longer [but will still strip eventually, so either way you need to wash it off after a minute.]

Comment: I will apply and see what happens, Thanks